# While rehashing a hashtable in c, system aborts when I try calling ht_put method

Tags: c

So basically the purpose of this post isn't necessarily to get help with my code, but rather to understand why my method of approaching this problem is giving me trouble.

I am trying to rehash a hashtable, and in doing so- i am dynamically creating a new hashtable, looping through the old one to get its contents, and attempting to "put" the key and the val of each bucket into the new hashtable by using a separate "ht_put" method.

I am getting *** glibc detected ***, followed by a bunch of garbage when I implement it this way though, and I would really like to know why. It can't be that I am trying to dynamically allocate with the same pointers as another hashtable did it with, is it?

Below is my api:

```
#ifndef HASHTABLE_T
#define HASHTABLE_T

typedef struct hashtable hashtable_t;
typedef struct bucket bucket_t;

struct bucket {
  char *key;
  void *val;
  bucket_t *next;
};

struct hashtable {
  unsigned long size;
  bucket_t **buckets;
};

unsigned long hash(char *str);

hashtable_t *make_hashtable(unsigned long size);
void  ht_put(hashtable_t *ht, char *key, void *val);
void *ht_get(hashtable_t *ht, char *key);
void  ht_del(hashtable_t *ht, char *key);
void  ht_iter(hashtable_t *ht, int (*f)(char *, void *));
void  ht_rehash(hashtable_t *ht, unsigned long newsize);
void  free_hashtable(hashtable_t *ht);

#endif
```

and here is the rehash function:

```
void  ht_rehash(hashtable_t *ht, unsigned long newsize) {
  unsigned long i;
  hashtable_t *new;
  new = make_hashtable(newsize);
  for(i = 0; i < ht->size; i++){
    bucket_t before_head = {.next = ht->buckets[i]};
    bucket_t *previous = &before_head;
    while(previous->next){
      char *key;
      void *val;
      key = previous->next->key;
      val = previous->next->val;
      ht_put(new, key, val);
      ht_del(ht, key);
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my put method:

```
  void ht_put(hashtable_t *ht, char *key, void *val) {
  unsigned int idx = hash(key) % ht->size;
  bucket_t *last = NULL;
  bucket_t *Next = ht->buckets[idx];
  bucket_t *current = NULL;
  while(Next && Next->key &&(strcmp(key, Next->key)!= 0)){
      last = Next;
      Next = Next->next;
    }
  if(Next && Next->key && strcmp(key, Next->key)==0){
    free(Next->key);
    free(Next->val);
    Next->key = key;
    Next->val = val;
  }
  else{
    current = malloc(sizeof(bucket_t));
    current->key = key;
    current->val = val;
    if(Next == ht->buckets[idx]){
      current->next = Next;
      ht->buckets[idx]=current;
    }
    else if(!Next){
      last->next = current;
    }
    else{
      current->next = Next;
      last->next = current;
    }
  }
}
```

The "garbage" im referring to is from the debugger, posted below:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./hashtable: free(): invalid pointer: 
0x000000000193a400 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3ad2875dee]

/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3ad2878c3d]

./hashtable[0x400929]

./hashtable[0x400e9c]

./hashtable[0x4012c3]

./hashtable[0x401390]

 /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x3ad281ed1d]
./hashtable[0x4006f9]
======= Memory map: ========

00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 6431721                            
/home/class/spring-18/cs351/ltrestka/cs351-spring18-
ltrestka/mps/02/hashtable

00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 fd:02 6431721                            
/home/class/spring-18/cs351/ltrestka/cs351-spring18-
ltrestka/mps/02/hashtable

0193a000-0195b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  
[heap]

3ad2400000-3ad2420000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2228287  
/lib64/ld-2.12.so

3ad2620000-3ad2621000 r--p 00020000 fd:00 2228287
/lib64/ld-2.12.so

3ad2621000-3ad2622000 rw-p 00021000 fd:00 2228287
/lib64/ld-2.12.so

3ad2622000-3ad2623000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0

3ad2800000-3ad298a000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2228288
/lib64/libc-2.12.so

3ad298a000-3ad2b8a000 ---p 0018a000 fd:00 2228288
/lib64/libc-2.12.so

3ad2b8a000-3ad2b8e000 r--p 0018a000 fd:00 2228288
/lib64/libc-2.12.so

3ad2b8e000-3ad2b90000 rw-p 0018e000 fd:00 2228288
/lib64/libc-2.12.so

3ad2b90000-3ad2b94000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0

3adc800000-3adc816000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2228352
/lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1

3adc816000-3adca15000 ---p 00016000 fd:00 2228352
/lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1

3adca15000-3adca16000 rw-p 00015000 fd:00 2228352
/lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1

7f46a4000000-7f46a4021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0

7f46a4021000-7f46a8000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0

7f46ab45e000-7f46ab461000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0

7f46ab47c000-7f46ab480000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0

7ffc48a6d000-7ffc48a82000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0  
                    [stack]
7ffc48b6c000-7ffc48b6d000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0 
                     [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0  
            [vsyscall]
okokmake: *** [test03] Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: That "garbage" being reported is quite important. If you build with debug information then it will contain file-names and line-numbers and probably even function names, and that can help to find out *where* the problem manifests itself, and might also give some hints about what the problem might be. So build with debug information (add the `-g` flag when building) and edit your question to include that dump, copied and pasted in full and without modification. Lastly, please [learn how to debug your own programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude apologies. I thought "garbage" was the term for it as I thought it was just spitting random addresses due to a fault in my code from poor pointer operations.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude and the errors i mentioned were with the debugger running, please check the edited post above as I cant fit them here. I am running on emacs.

Comment: You apparently use Linux (a very good point). Then consider compiling with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` (all warnings & debug info, with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...), improve the code to get no warnings, perhaps even use the [clang-analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/), and certainly use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), in addition of using `gdb`

Comment: If you temporarily comment out the ht_del() call, and replace it instead with `previous = previous->next`, does the crashing go away?  If so, that would suggest that ht_del() might be invalidating the `previous->next` pointer that you are using for your iteration.

Comment: However, you are the one learning C programming (be patient with yourself, it is [difficult](http://norvig.com/21-days.html)....). So spend more efforts and time in debugging (some bugs take several weeks to be found). And for your next question, consider providing some [MCVE]. Probably, you have bugs in part of your code that you don't show us. SO is not a fix-my-bug or do-my-homework service. Sometimes, drawing pictures (of your program running) on a board can help...

Comment: @JeremyFriesner No, when I comment out ht_del the problem remains the same. It specifically occurs when I call ht_push, but ONLY when I user previous->next->key, and previous->next->val as the parameters. It works fine otherwise. I suspected the problem might have been due to the use of a void pointer, or possibly in the fact that I am passing pointers that already exist. But if I dereference either of the values, I get segmentation faults.

Comment: Hmm.  I'd temporarily insert these calls just before the call to ht_put():  printf("previous=%p\n", previous); printf("previous->next=%p\n", previous->next);  ... most likely one or both of those two pointers is NULL or otherwise invalid, and printing out their values might clue you in regarding what the problem is.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner to be honest, I tried that already. I just removed it from the code here to reduce confusion. Those pointers that you stated are for the bucket_t type, but the keys and vals are valid when I print them. They have to exist at this point if the code is running, because that is the condition in my while loop.

Comment: @LucasTrestka if your `key` is your hashed value, and it relies on the number of buckets, how are you getting away with not rehashing your keys? (or is your rehashing handled in `ht_put`?)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin My keys are hashed in the ht_put method, sorry, i forgot to mention that.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I just edited in my put method, so as to avoid confusion in the future.

Comment: @LucasTrestka, I'm really confused. Where are you assigning the `new` hashtable to something that is visible back in the calling function? Your `ht_rehash` is type `void` and you never assign `new` to anything that can be seen outside of `ht_rehash` so what address do you have back in `main` for your new rehashed hashtable? I would expect your `ht_rehash` to have type `hashtable_t*` just like `make_hashtable`?? (and you would be assigning the return to something back in the caller)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Basically, what I am trying to do is take a hashtable as an argument, create a new hashtable, transfer the old keys and values into the new hashtable, free the data structures in the old hashtable and reassign them with the new indexes. This is not complete code, I stopped when I came across this error with ht_put because I would like to find out what exactly is happening. I'm stumped. I'm not trying to return a new hashtable, but rather update the one that was passed to it.

Comment: No, no... I get that. What I'm saying is where do you assign `ht = new;`? (e.g., you create `new` in `ht_rehash` -- but how does `new` get out of `ht_rehash` so it is usable?)  I suspect you are iterating over the old table in the caller and attempting to access addresses that have been freed and reassigned many times are you end up walking all over your memory and into the "*beyond...*".

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That is done in another method as well. Which returns a hashtable_t, In that method, I dynamically allocate space for a hashtable, set the hashtable_t->size and dynamically allocate (n, or hashtable_t->size) buckets, and return the value. In main, the make_hashtable method is called the same way.

Comment: @LucasTrestka - one link that provides a decent walk-through that might help (helped me a while back) is [Eternally Confuzzled - Hash Tables](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_hashtable.aspx)  It's worth a read just for any points that might help. (and with our back-and-forth you can see why the site requires [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- best I can do is guess.